# Problemas con Mediaquery

Tags: css, web, mediaqueries

Tengo entendido que para acceder al estilo de un elemento es con 'Element.style', pero con media query, esto no me funciona, ya que al pedir el valor, me devuelve 'undefined' y no 'none', que es como esta establecido en el media?

Este es el css principal

```
.header > ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Y este es el media:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){

    .header > ul{
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 20vw;
        right: 0;
        margin-top: 7.5%;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="responsive.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header"> 
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <ul id="menu">  
            <li>Accesorios</li>
            <li>Razas</li>
            <li>Contactenos</li>
            <li>Ubicación</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Olviden esta parte , es solo porque no me dejaba publicar tanto codigo.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu HTML para reproducir tu caso completo?

Comment: Ahi esta el HTML

Comment: Disculpame, no termino de entender que es lo que falla, por que reproduje tu ejemplo y a determinados pixeles se desaparece el menú como lo delimitaste en el CSS, ¿podrías aclarar un poco?

Comment: Con el responsive.css revisa, pero alli es mi duda, cuando no se aplica el media, todo bien, el 'element.style.display' si funciona, y me devuelve 'inline-block', que es el valor que le di en el css principal, pero al activarse el media (Cuando la resolucion disminuye), 'element.style.display' solo me retorna 'undefined', no se si deba utilizar otra propiedad que no sea style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el elemento está heredando la propiedad `display` desde una hoja de estilos, debes utilizar

```
getComputedStyle(elemento, null).display;
```

Como se puede observar en el siguiente fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu3Lsk84/

Adicionalmente, no deberías re-declarar toda la lista de estilos de la lista del header. Solo aquellos que deseas *sobreescribir* como el display.